# sqlite3 module cannot open database when started from ubuntu upstart

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, sqlite, upstart, forever

Working in Ubuntu server 14.04

I have an upstart .conf file in /etc/init for staring my node server. I am using forever. Here is what my script looks like

```
start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
expect fork
setuid myUserId

env HOME=/home/myUserId/
env NODE_BIN_DIR=/usr/bin
env NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript

script
PATH=$NODE_BIN_DIR:$NODE_PATH:$PATH
echo $PATH
exec forever start -o /home/myUserId/nodeServ/lServer/logs/out.log /home/myUserId/nodeServ/lServer/server.js 1337
end script
```

But I keep getting this error

```
Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
```

If I run the script from the command line exactly as it is in the conf file it works just fine. No problems. So I think it is a permissions issue. I have set permissions for read write execute on the database directory and the database and still I am unable to read from the file.

I have tried so many different things and I cannot figure out why this is happneing

**UPDATE:** This problem appears to not be isolated to upstart. I tried staring forever in shell script as well and I get the same errors.

I resolved my issue via workaround. Not using forever and starting node directly from the upstart file (allowing respawn). No issues. This appears to either be a sqlite3 issue or a forever issue.

Answer (score 0):

write this command `sudo chown www-data. .` in db file directory.

other solution is check file exists or not
ex :

```
var fs = require("fs");

var exists = fs.existsSync(dbfilepath);
```